# Securing programmatic access of a Node.js REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, oauth, token

I have a Node.js REST API which is usually consumed with a valid token after login from UI . The token generation and authentication happens on my node.js server only. I have to secure this API for **programatic access**.

For example, an "Add item to an inventory API". The API should allow adding item after a merchant logs in through the UI as well as through programmatic access from his end (Assume he has an automatic system which enables him to be able to do so periodically)

How do I secure such a system properly. I have few solutions in my mind to implement
this but what would be the most right way to do this ?

Comment: OAuth2 is a good default. Both your UI and your merchant can use the same API and authentication system.

Comment: Hi, are you suggesting we should have a third party here ? Cuz OAuth has three parties right ? In my case, I have only two parties.. can you guide me a bit in detail how you are suggesting to implement this ?

Comment: In your situation there are still 3 parties: the user, the API and your UI. Your UI effectively becomes the first user of your API.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to provide your merchant an API key in order to access your app's APIs. It's a very common pattern.

Comment: So, are you saying every user should be provided with unique API Keys ? As of now, I can anytime invalidate or block a user log in request when it comes through UI, I would like to maintain that privilege for programmatic access too.

Comment: That's right, every user would need their own unique API key. I don't see why you can't block/invalidate an API call just like a user log in request.